# Detect whats playing on desktop or device?

Tags: android, ios, macos, audio, browser

I'm interested in building either a website or a native desktop/mobile app, that is able to analyze in realtime anything that is being sent to the audio output of a given device that the website or native app is running on.

Please let me know of whether the following is possible and what web/browser based or native API I should use.

**Dekstop:**

So lets say I'm on my desktop computer and using Spotify in the background to play music. Is there a web/browser based API that would allow me to capture and analyze the Spotify music that is being played in the background? Would I have to create a native desktop app instead to do this?

**Mobile:**

If on my iOS or Android phone, I'm using the Spotify app to play music in the background, would it be possible to create a native app that would run at the same time on the device as the Spotify app, and capture and analyze the music that Spotify is sending to the audio output?

Comment: To your second question for android, yes it is possible and there are already many apps in google play store. Just search for audio analyzer.

Comment: I dont want an app. I want an API that I can use so I can integrate it into an my own app that will allow me to analyze any music or sounds that are being sent to the audio output.

Comment: In that case, you better edit the question to be specific and add android tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to interrupt the sound stream down low in the stack. This is done with tools like SoundFlower. You can see the source here;

https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower

Answer (score 1):

If the user plays only music, a roundabout method could be to use the recording device of the user which could be map to a music tune identifier (for instance Shazam).

You could then monitor in nearly real-time what tune the user is listening, regardless of the player he is using.